# Cannot boot after applying OpenCore Legacy Patcher Monteray for a MacBook5,1 (Late 2008 Aluminum Unibody)

Tags: boot, installation, macbook, macos-monterey

I'm attempting to use [OpenCore Legacy Patcher](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher) to update an Late-2008 aluminum unibody MacBook (`MacBook5,1`) to run Monterey (macOS 12).

##### What I did:

- On the target `MacBook5,1`, I downloaded the OpenCore app version `1.4.2` and built an OpenCore USB for Monterey 12.7.4
- I booted the machine from the OpenCore Monterey install USB
- I reformatted the system drive (Samsung SSD, internal) to a single 4TB APFS volume via disk utility
- I ran the Monterey installer onto this partition

##### What went wrong:

- After installation, the machine rebooted.
- Things are supposed to look [like this](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/BOOT.html), but did not.
- `OpenCore Install Monterey USB` is the only boot option (holding down `alt`)
- Selecting this option leads immediately to the "prohibit symbol"  (gray circle with a slash) and no further boot option.
- I tried resetting PRAM and SMC a few times to no effect

##### Research so far:

- I searched for an explicit walk-through and I found confusing information scattered across various forums (reflecting various historical states of OpenCore Legacy Patch, perhaps). There are some walk-throughs and forum posts for Monterey with `MacPro5,1`, but this is a desktop machine, I'm on the `MacBook5,1` (a laptop).
- OpenCore Legacy Patcher [does support](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/MODELS.html#macbook) `MacBook5,1`. I *am* attaching the install/boot USB stick through a USB2.0 hub to avoid USB1.0 support issues; I saw this mentioned a couple times but am not sure if it still applies.
- Up through the ["Building and installing OpenCore"](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/BUILD.html) steps, everything proceeds as planned.
- This [boot troubleshooting section](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Install-Guide/troubleshooting/boot.html#opencore-booting) may be relevant. After installation, the machine seems to lose the system drive entirely but also loses the EFI boot options for the `OpenCore Install Monterey USB`? Sadly, none of those scenarios, nor any in [this list](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Install-Guide/troubleshooting/extended/opencore-issues.html#stuck-on-a-black-screen-before-picker), seem to match the "prohibit logo" behavior I'm getting?
- [There is troubleshooting information for the () Prohibited Symbol here.](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/TROUBLESHOOTING.html#stuck-on-this-version-of-mac-os-x-is-not-supported-on-this-platform-or-(%F0%9F%9A%AB)-prohibited-symbol). The solution is to *"ensure you're booting OpenCore before the macOS installer in the boot picker. Reminder that the option will be called EFI Boot"*, however ***this boot option vanished immediately after installation.*** The other explanation is that there is something wrong with the USB drive, which doesn't *seem* plausible given that it is brand new and that I just ran the Monterey installer from it.

For now, I've re-installed Mojave and will try all of the above tomorrow (in case something different happens).

Comment: Is that MacBook *able* to run Monterey? I.E., is it in this list: https://support.apple.com/en-us/103260?

Comment: OpenCore has restore guides. Have you followed those?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik OpenCore is a utility that allows older Mac devices to run versions of MacOS that do not specifically support that hardware. It is a YMMV product, and they have their own compatibility table on their site, but in general, it actually works pretty well, if you stay within their defined limits.

Comment: @music2myear could you point me to a link for context? I started with a truly empty SSD, which now has a fresh Mojave (Patcher) install. I have only one Apple device & no time machine or remote backups. I can restore from images of the old (smaller) drive saved with `dd` on linux. I can do this (by moving drives into the Linux box), but restoring using `dd` is slow and will create a drive with a truncated MBR partition map, which as I understand will need to be wiped for Monterey OpenCore Patcher anyway.

Comment: There shouldn't be any MBR - GPT doesn't have MBR - and `dd` won't create any, truncated or otherwise, if the imaged drive was already GPT (it probably was because Apple used UEFI some years before it became the norm in PCs, therefore even in the original OS I wold expect an ESP (EFI System Partition) and GPT partitioning, not 'msdos' (AKA but wrongly "MBR", this actually being a mere characteristic/component of the aforementioned old partitioning type). Now... This rambling has little to do with your problem. Unfortunately I can't help with that, I don't use nor recommend Apple, ever.

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto; I suppose I meant "whatever the old format used to be, circa 2008". That's just GPT? My understanding is that OpenCore Legacy Patcher for newer OSs needed a different format. Hence, doing a fresh in stall on empty disk.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a situation where there is no EFI boot partition on either the main system disk, or the OpenCore Legacy Patcher Monterey install USB.

The older mac models cannot natively boot later operating systems. OpenCore's EFI bootloader provides the patches to make this possible. If you attempt to boot an unsupported operating system through the normal (Apple) bootloader, you'll see the  symbol.

[The OpenCore Legacy Patcher instructions](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Legacy-Patcher/BUILD.html) are slightly vague on this, but ideally one wants to click "Install OpenCore" for *both* the main system disk and the newly created USB thumb-drive installer, before attempting the install.

What happened was likely this:

- I installed OpenCore on the main system disk, which made it possible to boot the Monterey installer USB thumb drive.
- During installation, I erased my system disk, removing its EFI boot partition. Thus, the new system disk was not bootable.
- My OpenCore Legacy Patcher USB thumb drive did not have an EFI boot sector of its own, and so could not be used to boot the system either.

It's unclear to me whether the "Create macOS Installer" feature is *supposed* to create the EFI boot sector on the thumb drive, or whether I clicked something that skipped this step. The online OpenCore Legacy Patcher walk-through does not cover these steps in full resolution.

For future reference, one can manually install OpenCore onto the USB installer after it was created to make sure. Assuming your system drive is already partitioned as you would like, you *should* also be able to install OpenCore to the system disk and then run the patched installer, *provided* you *do not* alter the drive format in the process.